# C++ runtime error: Line 1061: Char 9: runtime error: addition of unsigned offset

Tags: c++, undefined, behavior

In [**this problem**](https://leetcode.com/problems/backspace-string-compare/)

> Given two strings s and t, return true if they are equal when both are typed into empty text editors. '#' means a backspace character.
>
> Note that after backspacing an empty text, the text will continue empty.

whenever I'm uncommenting the commented line (sc-- ;) I'm getting the following runtime error-

> Line 1061: Char 9: runtime error: addition of unsigned offset to 0x7ffeaeea2f00 overflowed to 0x7ffeaeea2eff (basic_string.h)
> SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/basic_string.h:1070:9

Can anyone please help me finding where I'm doing it wrong?

**Here's the code-**

```
bool backspaceCompare(string s, string t) {
    if(s.length()==0 && t.length()==0){
        return true;
    }
    
    int p1=s.length()-1, p2=t.length()-1;
    if(s[p1]!='#' && t[p2]!='#'){
        if(s[p1]!=t[p2]){
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    int sc=0, tc=0; 
    while((p1>=0) && (p2>=0)){
        if(s[p1]=='#'){
            sc=sc+2;      
        }
        p1--;
        if(sc>0){
            //sc-- ;  //I ain't getting the error when this line is commented, don't know what's wrong with this line!
        }
        
        if(t[p2]=='#'){
            tc=tc+2;
        }
        p2--;
        if(tc>0){
            tc-- ;
        }
        
        if(sc==0 && tc==0){
            if(s[p1]!=t[p2]){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    if(p1==0 && p2==0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `p1` or `p2` could be negative here: `if (s[p1] != t[p2]) {`  ??

Comment: Try to always use the `.at()` member function for index access and not the `[]` operator. It can help with catching out of bounds accesses which can cause undefined behavior.

Comment: `if(s.length()==0 && t.length()==0){` should probably use `||` instead of `&&`.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, Yaa that was the issue... Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

@JohnnyMopp has already mentioned the possible causes.
One point I would like to add is while dealing with the string while comparison or any other operation make sure your index value is not going negative, for example
If you are using a while loop like this `while(str[i]!='x' && i>=0)` then it might be possible you encounter the same error so it's better first check the index and then make the comparisons `while(i>=0 && str[i]!='x')` is not going to give you the error

Answer (score 0):

```
string (1)  
string& append (const string& str);   
substring (2)   
string& append (const string& str, size_t subpos, size_t sublen = npos);
c-string (3)    
string& append (const char* s);
buffer (4)  
string& append (const char* s, size_t n);
fill (5)    
string& append (size_t n, char c);
range (6)   
template <class InputIterator>
string& append (InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
initializer list(7) 
string& append (initializer_list<char> il);
```

> (1) string Appends a copy of str.
> (2) substring
> Appends a copy of a substring of str. The substring is the portion of str that begins at the character position subpos and spans sublen characters (or until the end of str, if either str is too short or if sublen is string::npos).

> (3) c-string Appends a copy of the string formed by the null-terminated character sequence (C-string) pointed by s.

> (4) buffer Appends a copy of the first n characters in the array of characters pointed by s.

> (5) fill Appends n consecutive copies of character c.

> (6) range Appends a copy of the sequence of characters in the range [first,last), in the same order.

> (7) initializer list Appends a copy of each of the characters in il, in the same order.

Comment: possible implementation of `std::string::append()`